# Shortcodes in Wordpress PHP files

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to insert an RSS feed into WordPress, using:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[events_rss feed='http://myeventsfeed']") ?>
```

In my standard page template, it works perfectly. However, I actually need it in a separate PHP file, which AJAX calls into a div into the standard page.

In my second PHP file though, something like

```
<?php echo "hello" ?>
```

is called through and displays properly on my standard page, but the first line of code does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a WordPress function, `do_shortcode`, in a regular PHP file. The WordPress environment isn't loaded therefore `do_shortcode` isn't available to you.

Run your AJAX request through WordPress instead.

Here's a good article from the Codex that should set you on the right path: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins